# Travel Grants for PhD student to Present Papers internationally (i.e. Korea) & nationally (i.e. USA)

Tags: phd, conference, funding, travel

Do you know of any available travel grants for PhD students (in any field, but if we must get specific -- archaeology/religion) to travel to conferences, both international or nationally, to present their research/papers? The conferences I'm presenting my papers at do not offer such funds and my institution is not capable of offering me enough funds to attend. However, it would be a disservice to me and my future to not attend and receive the feedback needed and expand my networks with other scholars in my field.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependent on the field and the university. Your department and your university most likely have travel grants you can apply for. Talk to your departmental administrators and whatever on-campus graduate student associations for more information on these. Professional societies also sometimes have travel grants and this depends on your field, but this is usually tied to their conferences. Lastly, you can always ask for your adviser to help you with grant money. He/she will likely be willing to pitch in if you're promoting his/her work (via your results).